# Can I get more information about 403 response from Apache HTTP?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have two supposedly identical systems but one gives a 403 to POST requests from a particular tool (SOAP UI). Can I get more information about the 403 from Apache?

Background is that the server also runs SELinux, mod_jk, SSL, Tomcat, Mod_Security but their respective log files haven't helped identify the reason behind the 403 response.

Comment: Can we get the output of the 403 message from the access log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `LogLevel` to `debug` and take a look at Apache's error log. I suspect that it caused by SELinux. You can temporary disable it to see if this error go away.